Lebesgue measure on R
$E\subset\mathbb{R},f:E\to\mathbb{R},E_\alpha:=\{x\in E:f'(x)\text{ exist},|f'(x)|<\alpha\}$.Proof that $\mathcal{L}^1(f(E_\alpha))\le \alpha\mathcal{L}^1(E_\alpha)$.
$\mathcal{L}^1$ means Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
I think Vitali Cover Theory may be useful, as for any $x\in E$, we can get $B(x,r_x)$ such that for any $r<r_x$, $|f(x+r)-f(x)|<\alpha$. Thus we get a cover of E and could get a countable cover by VCT.
But how I transform this cover to measure?
